# Find number of values before and after a character

Tags: vb.net, string, long-integer

I have the following variable.
I need to find how many numbers are before the decimal point and after the decimal point.

```
    Dim x As Long = 123.456
```

I have tried converting this into a string

```
    Dim xstr As String = x.ToString(x)
    Dim searchChar As String = "."
```

How can I display the number of characters before the decimal point.
i.e. '3'

and also, the number of characters after the decimal point.
'3'.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'm fairly sure that decimals are implicitly truncated when you assign them to a `Long`. That's probably what's causing you trouble.

Comment: Right.  `x` needs to be a `Float`, `Double`, or `Decimal`.  And you should be calling `x.ToString()` with no parameters, as opposed to `x.ToString(x)`.

Comment: Actually, you should be calling `ToString()` with `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `String.Split`, like this:

```
Dim x As Double = 123.456
Dim xstr As String = x.ToString()
Dim searchChar As String = "."
Dim parts() As String = xstr.Split({searchChar}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim firstLength As Integer = parts(0).Length
Dim secondLength As Integer = parts(1).Length
```

Comment: Hi, the code doesn't seem to allow me to use searchChar as the .xstr.Split attribute.

Comment: No luck when compiled ... would this code be after I have converted the integer into a string?

Comment: Yes.  I updated my answer to include the full example.

Comment: Actually mate, great stuff! Made it work, once the right variable types were set. Then with a simple Console.WriteLine((firstlength)) it was displayable. Thanks.

Comment: This works, assuming that `x` isn't a whole number. The code crashes when `x` is `123456.0`.

Comment: Right.  @StevenLiekens makes a good point.  I should have mentioned that you really should check `parts.Length` to make sure that it's `>= 2` before you try to access `parts(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `String.Substring()`:

```
Dim x As Double = 123.456

Dim xstr As String = x.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

Dim beforeDecimalSeparator As Integer = xstr.Length

Dim afterDecimalSeparator As Integer = 0

Dim decimalSeparatorPosition As Integer = xstr.IndexOf("."c)

If decimalSeparatorPosition > -1 Then

    beforeDecimalSeparator = xstr.Substring(0, decimalSeparatorPosition).Length

    afterDecimalSeparator = xstr.Substring(decimalSeparatorPosition + 1).Length

End If
```

Comment: Should just be `beforeDecimalSeparator = decimalSeparatorPosition` and  `afterDecimalSeparator = xtr.Length - decimalSeparatorPosition - 1`.

Comment: But then it's not based on substring :c

Comment: Then say it's based on `IndexOf` :)

Answer (score 0):

in your way:

```
xstr.Substring(xstr.IndexOf("."c) + 1)
```

But you do not need convert to String.

```
Dim y = x Mod 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IndexOf to solve this issue.

```
Dim x As Double = 123.456
Dim xstr As String = x.ToString()
Dim mIndex As Integer = xstr.IndexOf(".")
Dim firstLength  As Integer = mIndex;
Dim secondLength As Integer = (xstr.Length - mIndex) -1
```